# Can I get yahoo KOSPI KOSDAQ symbol list to use getsymbol function in R?

Tags: r

```
library(quantmod)
library(rpart)
library(rpart.plot)
library(stocks)
today <- Sys.Date()
kq <- getSymbols("^kq11", from = today-100, to = today, auto.assign = F)
```

R's quantmod package provide getSymbols function that call stock price information.

But I can not call many stock data to use loop. Because I don't know yahoo symbol list.

Can I get all yahoo KOSPI(Korea Composite Stock Price Index) KOSDAQ(Korea Securities Dealers Automated Quotations) symbol list to use getsymbol function in R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

today <- Sys.Date()
getSymbols("KRX:KOSPI200",src="google",auto.assign=F,from='2015-01-01','today')

Comment: You can make your answer clearer and looking better by adding some details on your proposed solution, and formating it using the WYSIWYG editor.